# Functions in React: my function isn't working, because of 'read-only' error. Why?

Tags: reactjs, function, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to write a function into a React component, but I am stuck with this error:

> Uncaught Error: Module build failed: SyntaxError: "productMap" is read-only

Why is this happening? And how can I fix this, so I can use `productMap`?

Here is my function:

```
printReceipt() {
    var products = this.props.updateBasket.products;

    //create a map of products

    const productMap = {};
    for(let product of products) {
        if(!productMap[product.id]) {
            productMap[product.id] = 1;
        } else {
            productMap = productMap + 1; 
        }
    }
    console.log(productMap);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

This is happening because `poductMap` is of type `const` and `const` cannot change through reassignment

Change it to a `let` or `var` instead

```
printReceipt() {
    var products = this.props.updateBasket.products;

    //create a map of products

    let productMap = {};
    for(let product of products) {
        if(!productMap[product.id]) {
            productMap[product.id] = 1;
        } else {
            productMap = productMap + 1; 
        }
    }
    console.log(productMap);
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

Answer (score 3):

Use `let productMap={};` instead of `const`.

> The const declaration creates a read-only reference to a value.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)

Comment: Thank you , i had simmillar  issue.

Answer (score 0):

use `()=> FunctionName()` instead of `FunctionName()`

When we call the function `FunctionName(`), it is just executed, but when we write `() => FunctionName()`, then it is only called when that particular operation is performed for example **onPress**.

`FunctionName()` sometimes doesn't work, and is only read-only, using `() => FUnctionName`, is a good way.

Comment: it's my pleasure, since you added the explanation, you can remove the first comment